# How to get only css from ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Can we get only css from ckeditor?

My html element:

```
<label>
    <textarea class="ckeditor" id="my-editor"></textarea>
</label>
```

data from ckeditor:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['my-editor'].getData();
```

My Data:

```
"<p><span style="font-family:comic sans ms,cursive"><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="color:#DAA520">Test Message</span></span></span></p>"
```

I can get data. But I only need css from it. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get the question but if you want to get the styles from that element you can do:

`document.getElementById('my-editor').style`

Answer (score 0):

There is no ckeditor methods to get inline css style. But if this styles set by ckeditor's 'styles' button, you can get styleset described in `contents.css`:

```
function myCallback(data)
     {
          return data;
     }
var styleSet = CKEDITOR.instances['my-editor'].getStyleSet(myCallback);
```